# Why does im4java Java API require a native executable?

Tags: java, imagemagick, im4java

Is it possible to run an [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) application without installing `ImageMagick-6.7.6-1-Q16-windows-dll.exe`?

Answer (score 4):

The [home page](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) explains it reasonably clearly:

> im4java is a pure-java interface to the ImageMagick commandline

and

> im4java [...] just generates the commandline for the ImageMagick commands and passes the generated line to the selected IM-command (using the java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start()-method).

How would you expect that to work without having the command line?

So to answer the question in the body of your post: no. As im4java is just a wrapper, you've got to have installed ImageMagick, as otherwise there's nothing for it to wrap!

Comment: @DuncanJones: I was answering the question in the title more than the question in the body. Will make it clearer.

Comment: It wasn't a complaint about your answer (I gave you a +1). I was being mildly flippant to the original poster...

Comment: @DuncanJones: I suspected that might be the case - but the clarification certainly won't hurt :)